# Using Oracle Forms(4.5) do_key commit_form fires which trigger and where is its code?

Tags: oracle, triggers

What tool is used to view the Key Triggers? Is it the `Oracle Terminal` for Windows?

`do_key('commit_form');` fires which trigger and where?

(we do not have all the tools and we want to convert, the DB is not even restored at this point) but I am assigned to figure it out. :)

We do not have even a .res (resource) file, and I am guessing this is used for mapping form fields to database columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do_key('commit_form');` would fire the KEY-COMMIT trigger, if there is one.  If there isn't one, it will just do the default action of that trigger, which is a commit.

Any key triggers would be in the form itself, most likely at the form level, and you would view the triggers using Oracle's Forms Builder.

The form field to database column mapping is also within the form.  The block properties will indicate which table or view, and the field properties will tell you which column.  In my experience, the fields and the columns usually have the same name, although that is not strictly necessary.